# SQL Server PRINT SELECT (Print a select query result)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select-query

I am trying to print a selected value, is this possible?

Example:

```
PRINT 
    SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Expense
```

Comment: Shimmy - thanks for selecting my answer as "the" answer.

Comment: The question asked about printing a value not about printing a table or a result set. In either case the language does not allow a sub query as an argument to the PRINT command. [Here is another SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193984/3368958) that shows an example very similar to this one with reference to the PRINT documentation.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You know, there might be an easier way but the first thing that pops to mind is:

```
Declare @SumVal int;
Select @SumVal=Sum(Amount) From Expense;
Print @SumVal;
```

You can, of course, print any number of fields from the table in this way.  Of course, if you want to print all of the results from a query that returns multiple rows, you'd just direct your output appropriately (e.g. to Text).

Comment: This is usually the best way, but for a nice solution when you have lots of rows & columns that you want to dump out with `print` see @DanFields answer below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36729681/8479

Answer (score 95):

If you're OK with viewing it as XML:

```
DECLARE @xmltmp xml = (SELECT * FROM table FOR XML AUTO)
PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @xmltmp)
```

While the OP's question as asked doesn't necessarily require this, it's useful if you got here looking to print multiple rows/columns (within reason).

Comment: This is _amazing_! There's so many cases where you'd want to use `PRINT` to dump out results and adding a custom proc for it is too much hard work. Great solution.

Comment: Yeah, I've used this in SSMS where adding a SELECT * FROM would cause problems for other applications/users.

Comment: On older versions of SQL Server you need DECLARE `@xmltmp xml;
SELECT @xmltmp = (SELECT * FROM table FOR XML AUTO);
PRINT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @xmltmp)`

Comment: Thanks @richard - FWIW though, if you're on anything older than SQL 2008R2, you're outside of MSFT's (extended) support window and should look to update.  Of course, that might not stop your workplace from continuing to use 2005 or whatever anyway...

Comment: Is there an online utility that can take the XML and show the data in a tabular form - online in the browser?

Comment: To add line breaks in the output for easier reading, use `PRINT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @xmltmp), '><', '>' + CHAR(10) + '<')`.

Comment: You can convert it to JSON as well in some versions of SQL server, just use FOR JSON instead of FOR XML

Comment: ` java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.`

Answer (score 37):

If you want to print multiple rows, you can iterate through the result by using a cursor.
e.g. print all names from sys.database_principals

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(128)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
PRINT @name
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name;
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Answer (score 9):

```
set @n = (select sum(Amount) from Expense)
print 'n=' + @n
```

Answer (score 6):

I wrote this SP to do just what you want, however, you need to use dynamic sql.

This worked for me on SQL Server 2008 R2

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[PrintSQLResults] 
    @query nvarchar(MAX),
    @numberToDisplay int = 10,
    @padding int = 20
as

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;

declare @cols nvarchar(MAX), 
        @displayCols nvarchar(MAX), 
        @sql nvarchar(MAX), 
        @printableResults nvarchar(MAX),
        @NewLineChar AS char(2) = char(13) + char(10),
        @Tab AS char(9) = char(9);

if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name = '##PrintSQLResultsTempTable') drop table ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable

set @query = REPLACE(@query, 'from', ' into ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable from');
--print @query
exec(@query);
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select Null)) AS ID12345XYZ, * into #PrintSQLResultsTempTable 
from ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable
drop table ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable

select name
into #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id =
object_id('tempdb..#PrintSQLResultsTempTable');

select @cols =
stuff((
    (select ' + space(1) + (LEFT( (CAST([' + name + '] as nvarchar(max)) + space('+ CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4)) +')), '+CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4))+')) ' as [text()]
    FROM #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
    where name != 'ID12345XYZ'
    FOR XML PATH(''), root('str'), type ).value('/str[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
,1,0,'''''');

select @displayCols =
stuff((
    (select space(1) + LEFT(name + space(@padding), @padding) as [text()]
    FROM #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
    where name != 'ID12345XYZ'
    FOR XML PATH(''), root('str'), type ).value('/str[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
,1,0,'');

DECLARE 
    @tableCount int = (select count(*) from #PrintSQLResultsTempTable);
DECLARE 
    @i int = 1, 
    @ii int = case when @tableCount < @numberToDisplay then @tableCount else @numberToDisplay end;

print @displayCols -- header
While @i <= @ii
BEGIN
    set @sql = N'select @printableResults = ' + @cols + ' + @NewLineChar from #PrintSQLResultsTempTable where ID12345XYZ = ' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + '; print @printableResults;'
    --print @sql
    execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@NewLineChar char(2), @printableResults nvarchar(max) output', @NewLineChar = @NewLineChar, @printableResults = @printableResults output
    print @printableResults
    SET @i += 1;
END
```

This worked for me on SQL Server 2012

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[PrintSQLResults] 
    @query nvarchar(MAX),
    @numberToDisplay int = 10,
    @padding int = 20
as

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;

declare @cols nvarchar(MAX), 
        @displayCols nvarchar(MAX), 
        @sql nvarchar(MAX), 
        @printableResults nvarchar(MAX),
        @NewLineChar AS char(2) = char(13) + char(10),
        @Tab AS char(9) = char(9);

if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name = '##PrintSQLResultsTempTable') drop table ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable

set @query = REPLACE(@query, 'from', ' into ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable from');
--print @query
exec(@query);
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select Null)) AS ID12345XYZ, * into #PrintSQLResultsTempTable 
from ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable
drop table ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable

select name
into #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id =
object_id('tempdb..#PrintSQLResultsTempTable');

select @cols =
stuff((
    (select ' + space(1) + LEFT(CAST([' + name + '] as nvarchar('+CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4))+')) + space('+ CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4)) +'), '+CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4))+') ' as [text()]
    FROM #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
    where name != 'ID12345XYZ'
    FOR XML PATH(''), root('str'), type ).value('/str[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
,1,0,'''''');

select @displayCols =
stuff((
    (select space(1) + LEFT(name + space(@padding), @padding) as [text()]
    FROM #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
    where name != 'ID12345XYZ'
    FOR XML PATH(''), root('str'), type ).value('/str[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
,1,0,'');

DECLARE 
    @tableCount int = (select count(*) from #PrintSQLResultsTempTable);
DECLARE 
    @i int = 1, 
    @ii int = case when @tableCount < @numberToDisplay then @tableCount else @numberToDisplay end;

print @displayCols -- header
While @i <= @ii
BEGIN
    set @sql = N'select @printableResults = ' + @cols + ' + @NewLineChar   from #PrintSQLResultsTempTable where ID12345XYZ = ' + CAST(@i as varchar(3)) + ' '
    --print @sql
    execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@NewLineChar char(2), @printableResults nvarchar(max) output', @NewLineChar = @NewLineChar, @printableResults = @printableResults output
    print @printableResults
    SET @i += 1;
END
```

This worked for me on SQL Server 2014

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[PrintSQLResults] 
    @query nvarchar(MAX),
    @numberToDisplay int = 10,
    @padding int = 20
as

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;

declare @cols nvarchar(MAX), 
        @displayCols nvarchar(MAX), 
        @sql nvarchar(MAX), 
        @printableResults nvarchar(MAX),
        @NewLineChar AS char(2) = char(13) + char(10),
        @Tab AS char(9) = char(9);

if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.tables where name = '##PrintSQLResultsTempTable') drop table ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable

set @query = REPLACE(@query, 'from', ' into ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable from');
--print @query
exec(@query);
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select Null)) AS ID12345XYZ, * into #PrintSQLResultsTempTable 
from ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable
drop table ##PrintSQLResultsTempTable

select name
into #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id =
object_id('tempdb..#PrintSQLResultsTempTable');

select @cols =
stuff((
    (select ' , space(1) + LEFT(CAST([' + name + '] as nvarchar('+CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4))+')) + space('+ CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4)) +'), '+CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4))+') ' as [text()]
    FROM #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
    where name != 'ID12345XYZ'
    FOR XML PATH(''), root('str'), type ).value('/str[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
,1,0,'''''');

select @displayCols =
stuff((
    (select space(1) + LEFT(name + space(@padding), @padding) as [text()]
    FROM #PrintSQLResultsTempTableColumns
    where name != 'ID12345XYZ'
    FOR XML PATH(''), root('str'), type ).value('/str[1]','nvarchar(max)'))
,1,0,'');

DECLARE 
    @tableCount int = (select count(*) from #PrintSQLResultsTempTable);
DECLARE 
    @i int = 1, 
    @ii int = case when @tableCount < @numberToDisplay then @tableCount else @numberToDisplay end;

print @displayCols -- header
While @i <= @ii
BEGIN
    set @sql = N'select @printableResults = concat(@printableResults, ' + @cols + ', @NewLineChar) from #PrintSQLResultsTempTable where ID12345XYZ = ' + CAST(@i as varchar(3))
    --print @sql
    execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@NewLineChar char(2), @printableResults nvarchar(max) output', @NewLineChar = @NewLineChar, @printableResults = @printableResults output
    print @printableResults
    SET @printableResults = null;
    SET @i += 1;
END
```

Example:

```
exec [dbo].[PrintSQLResults] n'select * from MyTable'
```

Comment: This SP is not working, whatever query i give it's says `incorrect syntax near near 'my query'`

Comment: This works for me on SQL server 2014. Testing other versions now.

Comment: Updated the post to include working versions on 2008 R2, 2012, and 2014.

Comment: Thanks for the update, working fine now. but in one table i got this error `Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Explicit conversion from data type timestamp to nvarchar is not allowed.
 ` i'll try to fix this conversion issue

Comment: Just need a small fix for NULL values.

select @cols =
stuff((
    (select ' , space(1) + LEFT(ISNULL(CAST([' + name + '] as nvarchar('+CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4))+')), '''') + space('+ CAST(@padding as nvarchar(4)) +'),

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
DECLARE @PrintVarchar nvarchar(max) = (Select Sum(Amount) From Expense)
PRINT 'Varchar format =' + @PrintVarchar

DECLARE @PrintInt int = (Select Sum(Amount) From Expense)
PRINT @PrintInt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print more than a single result, just select rows into a temporary table, then select from that temp table into a buffer, then print the buffer:

```
drop table if exists #temp

-- we just want to see our rows, not how many were inserted
set nocount on

select * into #temp from MyTable

-- note: SSMS will only show 8000 chars
declare @buffer varchar(MAX) = ''

select @buffer = @buffer + Col1 + ' ' + Col2 + CHAR(10) from #temp

print @buffer
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
PRINT 'Hardcoded table name -' + CAST(@@RowCount as varchar(10))
```

immediately after the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the undocumented [sp_MSforeachtable](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16977.aspx) stored procedure as such if you are looking to do this for every table:

```
sp_MSforeachtable @command1 ="PRINT 'TABLE NAME: ' + '?' DECLARE @RowCount INT SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ?) PRINT @RowCount"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish (like me) to have results containing mulitple rows of various SELECT queries "labelled" and can't manage this within the constraints of the PRINT statement in concert with the Messages tab you could turn it around and simply add messages to the Results tab per the below:

```
SELECT 'Results from scenario 1'
SELECT
    *
FROM tblSample
```

[image]

Comment: that does not quite answer the question but does work for me. => upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @select as nvarchar(max) = ''
SELECT @select  = @select  + somefield + char(13) FROM sometable
PRINT @select
```