# case subquery in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

the followings statements gives an error

**print (case 
        when exists (select count(*) from tblCustomerProductsDiscount PD where PD.cust_ID=138 and PD.pack_detl_ID = 1) then 0 end)**

*Error:* 
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Comment: just add a **SELECT** after print. that should do the trick and remove your error. **print ( select case when exists (select count(*) from tblCustomerProductsDiscount PD where PD.cust_ID=138 and PD.pack_detl_ID = 1) then 0 end)**

Comment: Don't use exists(count). Is very inefficient.

Comment: It gives the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, while your intention is quite clear, the script in its current form doesn't make sense, and here's why.

You are checking for the existence of rows in the `select count(*)...` subselect, but the fact is, `COUNT()` *always* returns a value. In case of no rows for the specified condition it will return `0`, but that would still be a row returned by the subquery, and `EXISTS` would evaluate to `TRUE` in any case.

To fix it, just replace `select count(*)` with `select *`.

Another thing is the error. *Subqueries are not allowed in this context*, and that is [final](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx). With `PRINT` you cannot use a subquery in any form. Store the result in a variable and `PRINT` the variable:

```
declare @result int;
set @result = case
  when exists (
    select *
    from tblCustomerProductsDiscount PD
    where PD.cust_ID=138 and PD.pack_detl_ID = 1
  )
    then 0
end

print @result;
```