# MS SQL Conversion failed when converting the varchar

Tags: sql-server

I expect to see an output of tables whtat have a date less then 201511 however  I keep getting an error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 
'

```
IF  (201504 < 201511) 
        begin
            (0 + 1 )  
        end' to data type int.
```

---

```
declare     @TableMonth int,
            @CurrentMonth int = 0,

@Table_Name =   'xx_'+CAST(@TableMonth as varchar)+'_T' ,
set @CurrentMonth = 'IF  (' + cast(@TableMonth as varchar) + ' < 201511) 
begin
            (' + cast(@CurrentMonth as varchar) + ' + 1 )  
end';
```

Comment: You are doing `SQL` like some procedural language. Lots of incorrect code here. Better show the actual data your table has and what you want to select.

Comment: cant show the data as it is confidential

Comment: This is a syntax issue that I am having

Comment: show not actual data, the data that is like you have.

Comment: This doesnt even have to do with my table data so theres no point in showing it. This is merely accessing a table with a date within the tablename

Comment: Ok I am done here. You obviously don't want to get help.

Answer (score 1):

You *are* trying to assign a varchar to an integer variable, so it shouldn't be surprising this fails - it's as if you're trying to build dynamic SQL without executing it.

Fortunately, the solution is rather simple:

```
set @CurrentMonth = case when @TableMonth < 201511 then @CurrentMonth + 1 end
```

I assume you handle year rollovers elsewhere.

Comment: So I tried this first but I get a syntax error near end of line so i do

Comment: heres the actual thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936975/return-data-before-current-month/33938749?noredirect=1#comment55641415_33938749

Comment: @MissR What kind of syntax error? It works fine for me. Maybe you need to use `select @CurrentMonth = case ...` on an older version of MS SQL, I'm not sure when it became possible to use `set` with any expression.

Comment: @MissR Oh, I see now - you have to remove the `,` before the `set`.

Comment: @MissR Well, must be something wrong with the code you have after this, then. Try to isolate the problem. "Still wouldnt work" doesn't really give us much to help you :)